# running a client/server prog on a single system

Tags: java, client-server

im wondering if there are two programs, one called `server` and the other called `client` and these two are illustrating a server and client respectively, is it possible to test them in one machine? considering i defined the client socket as follow:

```
socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",3000);
```

Edit:
Server part:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

class TCPServer
{
       private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
        private static Socket socket;
        private static PrintWriter toClient;
        private static BufferedReader fromClient;
        public static void run() throws IOException
            {
            System.out.println("Server is waiting for connections...");
            while (true)
            {
                openStreams();
                processClient();
                closeStreams();
            }

        }

        public static void openStreams() throws IOException
            {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(3000);
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            toClient = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
            fromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        }
        public static void closeStreams() throws IOException
            {
            fromClient.close();
            toClient.close();
            socket.close();
            serverSocket.close();
        }
      public static void processClient()throws IOException
{
    String msg = null;
    do {
        msg = fromClient.readLine();
        toClient.println("Client said " + msg);
    } while (!"exit".equals(msg));
}

        }
```

client part :

```
package clientserver.pkg1;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

class TCPClient
{
      private PrintWriter toServer;
            private BufferedReader fromServer;
            private Socket socket;
            public void Client( )throws IOException
                {
                socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",3000);
            }
            public void openStreams() throws IOException
         {

                toServer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
                fromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            }
            public void closeStreams() throws IOException
                {
                fromServer.close();
                toServer.close();
                socket.close();
            }
          public void run()throws IOException
{
    openStreams();
    String msg = "";
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (!"exit".equals(msg))
    {
        System.out.print(">");
        msg = scanner.nextLine();
        toServer.println(msg);
        String tmp = fromServer.readLine();
        System.out.println("Server said: " + tmp);
    }
    closeStreams();
}

            }
```

main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

       try
            {
                 TCPServer server = new TCPServer() {};
                 TCPClient client = new TCPClient();
                 client.run();
                 server.run();




            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                 System.err.println("Error in Client " + e.getMessage());
            }




java.lang.NullPointerException
```

## 1

```
toServer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
```

## 2

```
      public void run()throws IOException
{
    openStreams();
.....
}
```

## 3

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

       try
            {
                 TCPClient client = new TCPClient();
                 client.run();
            }
```

at `client.run();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly can, just have the client and server connected to the same port number.

Comment: so for this, should i run client and servers in two different program or in same? because when i do it, after running server all is ok but when i run client, it gives me 3 nullpointer exception, i put them as an edit in my post

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can write such a program. There is a [useful tutorial for this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html).
In short, it all boils down to prepare a ServerSocket:

```
ServerSocket createSocket() {
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(3000);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
        throw ex;
    }
    return serverSocket;
}
```

From the programmer's point of view, there is no difference between a server residing on a remote machine or on a local one.

You could try writing two different programs, one for the server and one for the client.
This is the main for the client:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
      TCPClient client = new TCPClient() {};
      client.run();
  } catch(IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Error in Client " + e.getMessage());
  }
```

And this for the server:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
      TCPServer server = new TCPServer() {};
      server.run();
  } catch(IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Error in Server " + e.getMessage());
  }
```

Then run the server first and then the client in a different console.

Comment: so for this, should i run client and servers in two different program or in same? because when i do it, after running server all is ok but when i run client, it gives me 3 nullpointer exception, i put them as an edit in my post

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace and the code that fails? Where does the NullPointerException appears?
So socket remains ''null'' and throws no exception?

Comment: i showed the 3 spots that exception happens but i will post the whole code here

Comment: I think that you should run the server and the client in two different programs or at least in two separate threads. With that code I don't understand how the server can accept() connections.

Answer (score 0):

sure, you can test them in the same machine,.
years ago i made the chatting-like application using socket, and i tested it to the same machine before i did that with some different machine, and that was go fine,.

Answer (score 0):

you can read/write on a port of your PC, independant from where in the network you are