# serversocket is not accepting connection?

Tags: java, macos, sockets

I am using a Mac and trying to run a server on my **local machine** . Here is the code

```
//1. creating a server socket
        providerSocket = new ServerSocket(0, 10);
        //2. Wait for connection
        System.out.println("Waiting for connection");
        try{
        connection = providerSocket.accept();
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
        System.out.println("Connection received from " +                   connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
```

I am seeing th print "Waiting for Connection" but not the print for  "Connection received from ..."
I see that code is still running, that means the accept() is blocked ? How can I fix this ?

Comment: Is the client application showing an error?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You create a server socket on a system-defined port (by specifying zero); you don't find out what port was actually allocated (by calling getLocalPort()); so you can't possibly connect to it with a client; so you aren't connecting to it; and you are surprised that accept() never unlocks and accepts a connection? Why?

Comment: Sonic and justDanyul righly identified the problem and gave me the solution(I even accepted their solution). 
I don't understand the compulsion to close this thread when my problem has been solved and I have accepted the solution.
So even if my thread is closed, I would like to give the audience the problems that I faced.
1. I ran a server and assumed that it failed to allocate the port.
Solution: Unless a client tries to connect the server would wait after the allocating the Port.
2. I failed to retrieve the allocated PORT number.
Solution:Look at extreme coder's solution at the end.

Comment: The 'compulsion to close your thread' was shared by five separate people. I'm one of them and I found your question essentially meaningless. It amounts to a complaint that `accept()` blocks. Well, it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

accept() blocks until a connection is made. Do you actually have a client attempting to access the socket? If not, I think it would be beneficial for you to give the following [java trail a run though](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html).

Comment: No, currently I do not have a client. But if I am using the same machine to run both server and a client how do I do this ?. I did some search on this , saw this thread "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580571/running-a-client-server-prog-on-a-single-system"
But it is still not very clear. 
Should I do in the same java project , with 2 different threads ? or 2 different programs ?

Comment: I think you should start by creating two different projects(one for the client and one for the server), and then read the link provided which leads to a implementation of a little the knock-knock client-server application they walk you though in that tutorial. This will give you a better understanding of what socket programming is :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to have a client which connects to this server. Till then server will wait.

Check this link :

http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-1996/jw-12-sockets.html

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `0` as the port number it means the `ServerSocket` would listen on any available free port. You have to make sure that a client connects to the server on that port. The port may be obtained by `ServerSocket.getLocalPort()`.

A better way is to hardcode the port number and make the client connect to that port.